# Log-log elasticities estimation

Tags: econometrics, elasticity

A simple linear regression model is given by $$\log(q)=b_1+b_2\log(p)+e$$ 
In this model $b_2$ is the derivative of $\log(p)$ with respect to $\log(p)$, that is, $$b_2=\frac{d \log(q)}{d \log(p)}=\frac{dq/q}{dp/p}$$
Question:
How do we obtain the the last equation? The first part of the last equation is clear. How do we obtain the second part?

Answer (score 2):

Chain Rule:
\begin{align*} \frac{d \log Q}{d \log P} &= \frac{d \log Q}{dQ}\frac{dQ}{dP}\frac{dP}{d\log P}\\ 
&=\frac{1}{Q}\frac{dQ}{dP}P
\end{align*}

Where last step you apply that $\frac{d \log Q}{dQ} = \frac{1}{Q}$ and that $\frac{dP}{d \log P} = P $.

---

If above argument made you feel uncomfortable, try this.
I'm going to use $Q$ to refer to quantity, $P$ to refer to price, $q$ to refer to the logarithm of quantity and $p$ to refer to the logarithm of price.

Let's say we have three functions:

- $q(Q) = \log Q$
- $Q(P)\quad$ this is the supply curve or the demand curve
- $P(p) = e^p\quad $ (hence $\log P = p$)

Consider function $q(Q(P(p)))$

By the Chain Rule:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dq}{dp} &= \frac{dq}{dQ} \frac{dQ}{dP} \frac{dP}{dp}
\end{align*}

That's just the standard-rule for the composition of a function. Then you apply $\frac{d \log Q}{dQ} = \frac{1}{Q}$. Also observe that $\frac{d \log P}{dP} = \frac{1}{P}$ hence $\frac{dP}{d \log P} = P$

$$ \frac{dq}{dp} = \frac{P}{Q} \frac{dQ}{dP} $$

Comment: Why you apply chain rule, if we take the derivative of $log(p)$  with respect to $log(p)$?

Comment: sorry, $log(q)$ with respect to $log(p)$

Comment: @davoh Because: (1) I can and (2) it allows me to obtain this result. I agree the change of variables can make it rather confusing, but it's really nothing more than two applications of the [Chain Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) and that $\frac{d}{dx} \log x = \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: thank you, but it's really confusing for me, In my perception here we haven't composition of two functions when we take a the derivative of $\log(q)$ with respect to $\log(p)$.

Comment: @davoh I'll be totally honest with you that I found this confusing as hell for awhile after I first encountered it (esp. the $\frac{d}{d \log P}$ part. It made it easier for me to understand initially by writing $p = \log P$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Matthew Gunn. By the way, i was looking for a proof in the literature, but didn't find it, have you ever find?

Comment: @davoh it's all over the place. It's totally standard calculus. Confusing at first, I agree, but it's totally standard stuff.

Comment: @davoh Econometric Methods by Johnston and DiNardo contains this derivation.